# Change Cell alignment in Array environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

Can anyone please tell me how to align the alphabets A,B,C,D and E in the array environment so that I can move each of them to the yellow spot?

I have attached my code below

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} 
\textbf{Question 16}\\
The graph of the function $y=f(x)$ is shown below
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
title={$ $},
xlabel={$ $},          % default put x on x-axis
ylabel={$y$},   % default put y on y-axis
ticks=none
}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.1,ymax=0.45,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
The corresponding part of the graph of the derivative function $y = f'(x)$ is best represented by
\begin{center}
\setlength\arraycolsep{5pt} % default is "5pt"
$\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{A.} &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
ticks=none
}}
\raisebox{-0.01\height}{    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}  &
\textbf{B.}  &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
title={$ $},
axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
ticks=none
}}
\raisebox{-0.01\height}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\textbf{C.}  &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
ticks=none
}}
\raisebox{-0.01\height}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:0] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain= 0:3.5] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}} &
\textbf{D.}  &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
    axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
    ticks=none
}}
\raisebox{-0.01\height}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:0] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain= 0:3.5] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\textbf{E.}  &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
ticks=none
}}
\raisebox{-0.01\height}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.45,ymax=0.1,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {-exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: change all the  `\raisebox{-0.01\height}` lines to something like `\raisebox{-0.9\height}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desired vertical align of A,B,C,D and E with top of plots can be achieved with determine baseline of plots around top of their bounding box:

[image]

In the code of MWE below

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}% <-- new
\tikzset{plotalign/.style = {baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}}}% <-- new

\usepackage{array,booktabs}% <-- new
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={% <-- now common for all plots
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
ticks=none
}}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Question 16}\\
The graph of the function $y=f(x)$ is shown below

    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.9,
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.1,ymax=0.45,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
The corresponding part of the graph of the derivative function $y = f'(x)$ is best represented by

    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c c >{\bfseries}c c}
A. &
\begin{tikzpicture}[plotalign]
\begin{axis}[scale=0.9,
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
    &   B.  &
\begin{tikzpicture}[plotalign]
\begin{axis}[scale=0.9,
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}               \\
    \addlinespace
    C.  &
\begin{tikzpicture}[plotalign]
\begin{axis}[scale=0.9,
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:0] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain= 0:3.5] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
    &   D.  &
\begin{tikzpicture}[plotalign]
\begin{axis}[scale=0.9,
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis 
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:0] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain= 0:3.5] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}               \\ 
    \addlinespace
E.  &
\begin{tikzpicture}[plotalign]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
xmin=-4,xmax=4,
ymin=-0.45,ymax=0.1,
]
\addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {-exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

are added two packages: `array` and `booktabs`, defined is `\tikzset` for style used in aligning plots labels (A, B,...,E) with top of plots. Also `\plotsset` for all plots is defined only ones in preamble, since they were equal at all those plots. By this the code is more concise. The construct $\begin{array} ...\end{array}`, which intention/benefits are not clear to me, is replaced with`tabular` environment.

As can  be seen, all `\raisebox` boxes are omitted. Also contain some small changes in table design: with `addlinespace` from `booktabs` is determined space between table rows, `scale`, which can be omitted without observable changes of figure , is moved from `tikzpicture` to `axes` where works more properly (regarding scaling of fonts in plots).

Answer (score 1):

You should *drop*  the `tikzpicture`s by their `\height` (or raise them by `-\height`) as well as a correction for the baseline skip which, under `array`, is stored in `\normalbaselineskip`. Since the `tikzpicture` has a little more whitespace around its border, we can increase this `\normalbaselineskip` to `1.5\normalbaselineskip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} 
\textbf{Question 16}\\
The graph of the function $y=f(x)$ is shown below
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
  axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
  axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
  axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
  title={$ $},
  xlabel={$ $},          % default put x on x-axis
  ylabel={$y$},   % default put y on y-axis
  ticks=none
  }}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \begin{axis}[
      ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
      xmin=-4,xmax=4,
      ymin=-0.1,ymax=0.45,
      ]
      \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
The corresponding part of the graph of the derivative function $y = f'(x)$ is best represented by
\begin{center}
  \setlength\arraycolsep{5pt} % default is "5pt"
  $\begin{array}{cccc}
    \textbf{A.} &
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
      axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
      axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
      axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
      xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
      ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
      ticks=none
      }}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1.5\normalbaselineskip}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
          xmin=-4,xmax=4,
          ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
          ]
          \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}}  &
    \textbf{B.}  &
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
      axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
      axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
      title={$ $},
      axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
      xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
      ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
      ticks=none
      }}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1.5\normalbaselineskip}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
          xmin=-4,xmax=4,
          ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
          ]
          \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}}\\
    \textbf{C.}  &
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
      axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
      axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
      axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
      xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
      ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
      ticks=none
      }}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1.5\normalbaselineskip}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
          xmin=-4,xmax=4,
          ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
          ]
          \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:0] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
          \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain= 0:3.5] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}} &
    \textbf{D.}  &
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
        ticks=none
    }}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1.5\normalbaselineskip}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
          xmin=-4,xmax=4,
          ymin=-0.8,ymax=0.8,
          ]
          \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:0] {x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
          \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain= 0:3.5] {-x*exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}}\\
    \textbf{E.}  &
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
      axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
      axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
      axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
      xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
      ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
      ticks=none
      }}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1.5\normalbaselineskip}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \begin{axis}[
          ylabel={$ $}, % default put y on y-axis
          xmin=-4,xmax=4,
          ymin=-0.45,ymax=0.1,
          ]
          \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {-exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}}
  \end{array}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```